# SQL get latest record for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-tables

I have three tables that contains data as below:

**Users**

```
Id   Name     Other_Columns
---------------------------
1    John     Blah
2    Ricky    Blah
3    Stella   Blah
4    Bob      Blah
```

**Saldo**

```
Id   User_id   Saldo
--------------------
1    3         0.00
2    1         9.00
3    2         0.15
4    4         3.50
```

**Payments**

```
Id   User_id   Amount     Paid_date
------------------------------------------
1    2         10.00      2014-09-01 08:10
2    2         25.00      2014-09-01 09:00
3    3         100.00     2014-05-10 12:47
4    1         20.50      2014-02-23 15:30
```

How to get result like this:

```
Id   Name     Saldo     Last Payment
------------------------------------------
1    John     9.00      23.02.2014 20.50
2    Ricky    0.15      01.09.2014 25.00
3    Stella   0.00      0000-00-00 0.00
4    Bob      3.50      10.05.2014 100.00
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can a user have more than one row on the SALDO table?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia, No, each user has only one row in Saldo table

Comment: ok the answer I posted should work then, if not let me know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select u.id, u.name, s.saldo, p.last_paid_date, p2.amount
  from users u
  join saldo s
    on u.id = s.user_id
  join (select user_id, max(paid_date) as last_paid_date
          from payments
         group by user_id) p
    on u.id = p.user_id
  join payments p2
    on p.last_paid_date = p2.paid_date
   and p.user_id = p2.user_id
```

This answer assumes:

(1) On table SALDO, there is one row per USER_ID

(2) On table PAYMENTS, there can be multiple rows per USER_ID

(I'm pretty confident about #2 being true, I don't know about #1, as you didn't say and your sample data doesn't indicate one way or the other)